# How to get x,y,z location from a list with python?

Tags: python

How to get location from a list with python?

`list = ["Cube1","Cube2", "Cube3"]`

How can I get the Y location for the list?

I can get it for each individual object:

```
C1= bpy.data.objects["Cube1"].location
```

But I don't know how to convert list to [(X,Y,Z),(X,Y,Z),(X,Y,Z)]

Comment: `loclist = [bpy.data.objects[name].location[:] for name in namelist]`?  Or `.location.y` for the Y's? But maybe is this a Python question, not a Blender question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming we have the default cube and three clones as our object names, we can build new lists for the locations, and the Y locations. You asked for both in the question and I was unsure which you actually wanted...

```
import bpy

list = ["Cube","Cube.001", "Cube.002", "Cube.003"]
locations = []
yLocs = []

for n in list:
    locations.append( bpy.data.objects[n].location )
    yLocs.append( bpy.data.objects[n].location.y )
    
print( locations )
print( yLocs )
```